# Why stream is fetching data of the previous user even after logging out & again logging the new user?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I'm having a flutter application in which if I login user A, all the data from collection is being fetched correctly.
The moment I logout user A and login user B, the current user is being changed but still fetching the collection data with user A uid.
If I again logout and login with user C, current user is being changed but still all the data are being fetched with user A uid only.

I tried to reload the user, refresh the token manually, logged out from all providers, even remove all the routes from the stack, but still didn't get the result.

This is previous user from FIREBASE:
User(displayName: User A, email: usera@gmail.com, isEmailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2023-08-07 19:09:04.926Z, lastSignInTime: 2023-08-15 18:38:10.163Z), phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: User A, email: usera@gmail.com, phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid: usera@gmail.com)], refreshToken: null, tenantId: null, uid: iceESRpOmtaWWjeE1VTlMMrOAro1)

This is newly logged in user from FIREBASE:
User(displayName: User B, email: userb@gmail.com, isEmailVerified: false, isAnonymous: false, metadata: UserMetadata(creationTime: 2023-08-07 19:09:04.926Z, lastSignInTime: 2023-08-15 18:38:10.163Z), phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerData, [UserInfo(displayName: User B, email: userb@gmail.com, phoneNumber: null, photoURL: null, providerId: password, uid: usera@gmail.com)], refreshToken: null, tenantId: null, uid: 3xvFuzudBbWf1qy8L1otH2Ft0fy1)

This is previous user data from COLLECTION:
PREVIOUS UserModel(uid: iceESRpOmtaWWjeE1VTlMMrOAro1, name: User A, email: usera@gmail.com, status: true, createdAt: 1691435312287, updatedAt: 1692124235394)

This is current user data from COLLECTION:
CURRENT UserModel(uid: iceESRpOmtaWWjeE1VTlMMrOAro1, name: User A, email: usera@gmail.com, status: true, createdAt: 1691435312287, updatedAt: 1692124235394)

This is stream provider in multiprovider:

```
StreamProvider<UserModel?>(
          initialData: null,
          create: (_) => firestoreService.getUserStreamDetail(),
          updateShouldNotify: (p, c) {
            console.log('PREVIOUS $p, CURRENT $c');
            return true;
          },
        )
```

This is function to get user data from COLLECTION:

```
Stream<UserModel>? getUserStreamDetail() {
    try {
      if (user != null) {
        return firestoreReference.doc(user!.uid).snapshots().map((doc) {
          log('USER DATA ${doc.data()}');
          return UserModel.fromSnapshot(doc);
        });
      }
      return null;
    } on FirebaseException catch (e) {
      log('26 ERROR $e');
      ToastFunctions.showWarningToast(e.message ?? 'Something went wrong...');
      rethrow;
    } catch (e) {
      log('30 error $e');
      ToastFunctions.showWarningToast(e.toString());
      rethrow;
    }
  }
```

Comment: You don't share how your `user` variable is initialized, but it stands to reason that it still points to the previous user when you call Firestore inside `getUserStreamDetail`.

Comment: Yes. It points out to the previous user itself while fetching the data from collection. Though current user is being changed every-time while login/logout.

Comment: The results you're getting seem to indicate otherwise. It's gonna be hard to say why that is without seeing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)" and [Build a minimal, complete, reproducible example](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/minimal-complete-reproducible-example)